# JSF SelectOneMenu not setting default value

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am using a h:selectOneMenu with a f:converter but I am having issues to set and get the value present on bean and to list a default value also.

Here is the h:selectOneMenu:

> `<h:selectOneMenu  align="left"  styleClass="fill" value="#{serviceController.searchAlias}">
>       <f:converter converterId="aliasConverter" />
>       <f:selectItems value="#{serviceController.aliasTypesList}"  var="aliasItem" itemLabel="#{aliasItem.typeName}"/> 
>       <f:ajax />
>   </h:selectOneMenu>`

On my Session bean I have:

```
...

On constructor...

 private Alias searchAlias = null;
 this.searchAlias = new Alias();
 this.searchAlias.setTypeCode("4");
 this.searchAlias.setTypeName("Test");

...

Setters and getters...

 /**
 * Gets the searchAlias.
 * 
 * @return the searchAlias
 */

public Alias getSearchAlias() {
     LOGGER.debug("GET SEARCH"+ this.searchAlias);
    return this.searchAlias;
}

/**
 * Sets the searchAlias.
 * 
 * @param searchAlias the searchAlias to set
 */

public void setSearchAlias(Alias searchAlias) {      
    LOGGER.debug("---------------setting ALIAS" + this.searchAlias.getTypeCode() + " " + this.searchAlias.getTypeName());
    this.searchAlias = searchAlias;
}
```

The list items are well displayed, which is a list of Alias objects, so I think the problem is not related with the converter. 
The problem is that the default value on combo box should be "Test".
If I print searchAlias object it is well populated with the values that I gave, so I do not understand why this **value="#{serviceController.searchAlias}"** is not working .
Can you help me please?

Comment: how your Alias equals() looks like?

Comment: @Leo /**
     * Override method toString()
     * 
     * this object string
     */
    Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.typeCode + "|" + this.typeName;
    }

    /**
     * Override method equals
     * 
     * object the object to compare
     */
    Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        boolean result = object != null ? ((Alias) object).typeCode.equals(this.typeCode) : false;

        return result;
    }

Comment: try generating the default equals() using eclipse and using it instead of yours